# PowerBI Online Service Display of Parameter Values

Tags: powerbi

I have a report with Start/End date parameters which the User can update in the Online PowerBI Service, and when I upload the report, I also have a card displaying (next to the report grid) to show the value the parameters are set to -- since it behooves anyone viewing the report to know what those parameters are.

The problem I have is what would seem to be an obvious requirement, and that is -- if the User changes the parameter in the PowerBI service and refreshes -- the card should display the new values.

However, while the User can change the parameter in the Online PowerBI service, there appears to be no way of knowing (other than going to Settings | Parameters) what that value is.  The card, at this point, still reflects the initial uploaded value and is not tracking the current value.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be an [issue](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Query-parameters-displayed-value-doesn-t-refresh-in-Power-BI/td-p/567445/page/3) that was identified a while ago by some other users.

The above link doesn't provide a solution exactly to the issue but more of a work around which is to convert the parameter value into a table which should then reflect the updated value onto the card.

That being said, it might be worth ensuring that after the parameter is changed then the data set is refreshed before the report is refreshed.

I created a simple date parameter displayed on a card, deployed it online and updated the parameter. Without refreshing the dataset the value would not update. After refreshing the dataset the card then showed the current value.